# MySQL COUNT in WHERE OR statement

Tags: mysql, count

I found the answer on my own. But cause a lot of people searching for the sam thing i want so share my solution:

My example tables:

```
t_employes                    t_increases
id | name | salary            employe_id | year
------------------            -----------------
1  | Jon  | 3000              1          | 2005
2  | Ben  | 3000              1          | 2008
3  | Tom  | 2499              2          | 2007
```

What I need:

```
SELECT 
   t_employes.name,
   t_employes.salary,
   COUNT(t_increases.employe_id) AS count_increases
FROM
   t_employes
   LEFT JOIN t_increases ON t_employes.id = t_increases.employe_id 
WHERE
   t_employes.salary < 2500
   -- OR count_increases < 2 -- (error)
   -- OR COUNT(t_increases.employe_id) -- (error)
GROUP BY t_employes.name
```

I couldn't use HAVING because i need my condition in an OR statement

Comment: You could put both the ORed conditions in the HAVING clause. Or do 2 queries unioned together, one with the HAVING clause and the other checking the salary.

Comment: There are 100 ways to solve this problem. But i want it take place BEFORE the aggregation. Now i can also combine it with condtitions i can't use in HAVING clause. And thats why i asked for a solution to place it in the WHERE clause. See the title. And i answered it. And it works. So why the bad rating? As your solution is the only one.

Comment: I haven't rated it. Problem with your solution is merely in performance as mysql tends to poorly optimise an IN clause with a sub query. Not sure why you feel you cannot use the OR in the having clause.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working with an COUNT statement in a WHERE clausel:

```
SELECT 
    t_employes.name,
    t_employes.salary,
    COUNT(t_increases.employe_id) AS count_increases
FROM
    t_employes
    LEFT JOIN t_increases ON t_employes.id = t_increases.employe_id 
WHERE
    t_employes.salary < 2500 OR
    t_employes.id IN (SELECT employe_id FROM t_increases GROUP BY employe_id HAVING COUNT(year) < 2)
GROUP BY t_employes.id
```

Comment: That's why mysql `GROUP BY` is strange. In other dbms you should use `..GROUP BY t_employes.name, t_employes.salary..` since you put those columns in select statement without aggregate function.

Comment: So whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions that avoid a sub query.

Firstly putting the check for the count and the salary in the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT 
   t_employes.name,
   t_employes.salary,
   COUNT(t_increases.employe_id) AS count_increases
FROM
   t_employes
   LEFT JOIN t_increases ON t_employes.id = t_increases.employe_id 
GROUP BY t_employes.name
HAVING t_employes.salary < 2500
OR count_increases < 2
```

2nd solution which does 2 queries, one for each condition and uses UNION to merge the results together

```
SELECT 
   t_employes.name,
   t_employes.salary,
   COUNT(t_increases.employe_id) AS count_increases
FROM
   t_employes
   LEFT JOIN t_increases ON t_employes.id = t_increases.employe_id 
WHERE
   t_employes.salary < 2500
GROUP BY t_employes.name
UNION
SELECT 
   t_employes.name,
   t_employes.salary,
   COUNT(t_increases.employe_id) AS count_increases
FROM
   t_employes
   LEFT JOIN t_increases ON t_employes.id = t_increases.employe_id 
GROUP BY t_employes.name
HAVING count_increases < 2
```